# Can we use 'inquisitive questions'?

Tags: adjectives, vocabulary

Inquisitive means curious or questioning. So would using 'inquisitive' as an adjective for questions be redundant?

Comment: You said yourself that Inquisitive means questioning, so, yes. It is redundant. What are you trying to imply with those words?

Comment: Don't ask [nosey questions!](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22nosey+questions%22) In fact, don't even ask *questions* - just ***ask**!*

Comment: Inquisitive means curious too. And 'curious' question is correct. So I thought an 'inquisitive' question would also be correct. Wasn't sure though because of the ambiguity in the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

It might be redundant in normal usage, but it wouldn't be redundant in the right context.

For instance, you might be trying to contrast one type of question with another. In which case, you need to use adjectives in order to distinguish between them:

> Was that actually an *inquisitive* question or just a *rhetorical* question?